# User validation process in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to get this user validation process on the insert method, here is the part of the function that seems like it is not working:

```
exports.insert = (req, res) => {

    let validEmail = false;


    userModel.findByEmail(req.body.email)
        .then((result)=>{
            if(result) {
                console.log("ok"+result)
            }
            else{
                console.log("nok"+result);
                validEmail = true;
                //returns true when a not used email is posted
            }
        });

    let validPassword = validatePassword(req.body.password);
    console.log(validEmail, validPassword); //always returns false for validEmail

    //If statement to verify if both validEmail and validPassword are "true"
```

The password validation works properly (pretty straight forward as of now), but what keeps not working is the email validation.
Since i'm using the email as the identifier for the authentication I need it to be unique, so I'm using the findByEmail which is as follow :

```
    exports.findByEmail = (email) => {
    return  User.findOne({"email":email})
        .then((result) => {
            if(result) {
                result = result.toJSON();
                delete result.__v;
                delete result.password;
                return result;
            }else{
                return null;
            }
        })
    };
```

It does work but it seems like the

```
validEmail = true
```

happens after the if statement. When i console.log if the else statement, it does affect true to validEmail but it doesn't go in the if statement afterwards.

Is there something wrong?

edit : here is the validatePassword function:

```
function validatePassword(password){
    return password.length>6;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be that you spin off promise hence it runs asynchronously and continue to validate password. This (password validation) should be in the `then` block of the Promise when email is not found, in your case.

Comment: I actually set validPassword outside att the beginning with validEmail so that I know if only the email or password doesn't match. I added the validateEmail function, but as i said the password verification works pretty fine; but is it what is causing the problem?
Also I added 2 console.logs with the result of each of them

Comment: well, check on promises and async code, that is your trouble there imho.the variable is not set (yet) when your code reaches the if statement. put breakpoint on if line and validEmail=true line and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I got the answer thanks to @PeS

Basically i wasn't waiting for the answer of my asynchronous function findByEmail.
What I did is chain .then blocks as this, not sure if this is the best way though:

```
    let validEmail = false;
    let validPassword = req.body.password.length>6;

    userModel.findByEmail(req.body.email)
        .then((result)=>{
            if(!result){
                validEmail = true;
                console.log("1"+validEmail)//returns true
            }
        }).then(() => {
        if(validEmail && validPassword){
            let salt = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64');
            let hash = crypto.createHmac("sha512", salt).update(req.body.password).digest("base64");
            req.body.password = salt + "$" + hash;
            req.body.permissionLevel = 1;
            userModel.createUser(req.body)
                .then((result) => {
                    res.status(201).send({id: result._id});
                })
        }else {
            if (!validEmail && validPassword) {
                res.status(409).send({"Error": "Email already used."});
            }  else if(!validPassword && validEmail){
                res.status(409).send({"Error":"Password is not valid"})
            }else{
                res.status(409).send({"email": "Email already used.", "password": "Password is not valid."})
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Frankly, this is not the way to go around here. You wrote your answer based on mine - even giving me credit there - and accept that. Not fair.

Comment: I actually changed the way i did it. Yes I gived you the credits and thanked you, isn't that enough? But here are the points, sorry for clicking the wrong answer...